# Bootstrap 5 navbar with different menu toggle breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a navbar in Bootstrap 5 with two toggle icons that collapse at different breakpoints. I currently have the following:

Display when media >= 992px:

[image]

Display when media < 992px:

[image]

The main menu is working as intended, it collapses to an off-canvas menu and displays the hamburger menu media < 992px. But for the search menu, I would like to display the magnifying glass icon at all sizes, and when toggled display the search input box.

In summary, how can I toggle the main menu when <992px, but toggle the search menu at all media sizes?

[Link to Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/CNa7fRDQt6)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#navbarMainMenu" aria-controls="navbarMainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle main menu">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
    
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start offcanvas-menu" tabindex="-1" id="navbarMainMenu" aria-labelledby="navbarMainMenu">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSearchMenu" aria-controls="navbarSearchMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle search menu">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSearchMenu">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="search" />
        <span class="input-group-text">Search</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This is handled by the `navbar-expand-lg` class on the nav element. You can't have different behaviors within the same navbar without manually overriding CSS to your liking.